# Update Panel Not working on Server (IIS7)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, iis-7, updatepanel

So I developed an application and is working perfectly on my localhost. Put it on my server (IIS7) and now my Update Panels aren't working. I had an update panel checking user inputs ontextchanged with an autopost back, which was in an update panel.

Can't figured out why this is, my hosting company says its to do with my application. They gave me a handler to copy into my web.config file but this hasn't worked.

What could I try to locate the error?

```
<system.webServer>
          <handlers>

          <add name="Ajax" path="*.axd" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />

          </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Are you sure an UpdatePanel is the best thing to do here? Do you need to  cause a PostBack with every single keystroke?

Comment: Well its only being used for Sign Up page, which checks to see if User Name is available or Email is already exists. Its causing a refresh of the screen but with the update panel it doesn't.

Comment: I think you'll find that using AJAX directly instead of an UpdatePanel would be easier. You can then add in a debouncer. You only really care when they pause in their typing to check. If you check it on every keystroke, that's a heavy server load and a lot of wasted bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your IIS manager, go to your site and select "Handler Mappings", then on top right select "Revert to inherited"

Answer (score 0):

> Try opening your IIS manager, go to your site and select "Handler Mappings", then on top right select "Revert to inherited"

This worked thank you @QatQat